# Does Inno Setup require a restart after installing fonts?

Tags: fonts, inno-setup

I am deploying a program with Inno Setup, and part of it requires installing some fonts to the system. No problem - I just used `DestDir: "{fonts}"; FontInstall: "...";` in my `[Files]` section.

However, I am unable to tell if the system needs a restart afterwards. I know that copying fonts from the command line normally does require a restart.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to force the system to restart. As the [`Font Installation and Deletion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article says, all what the application, which modifies the font table should do, is notify all the applications about this change by sending the [`WM_FONTCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. And that's what Inno Setup tries to do internally in its [`InstallFont`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Install.pas#L788) nested procedure.

Though, there is one exception when that message is not being broadcasted and it's the case when you specify the [`restartreplace`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=restartreplace) at your font file entry, and Inno Setup could not overwrite an existing font file for some reason. In that case Inno Setup itself asks user to restart the system, so you still don't have to do anything.

Comment: Fantastic, that is great to know.